# Is the instrumental case used for comparatives?

Tags: творительный-падеж

I'm watching the 1987 James Bond movie *The Living Daylights* with Russian subtitles.

In the scene where Bond first spots the main female character, he says, in English:

> "Sniper. Two floors up, center window."

In the Russian subtitles, this has been translated as:

> "Снайпер. Двумя этажами выше, центральное окно."

What's the reasoning behind the use of the instrumental case in this sentence? I'm generally familiar with most uses of the instrumental case; its use with prepositions, verbs, to answer кем/чем, etc., but in this particular instance, I can't figure out what's going on.

If there is a rule, please state it and provide further examples of how it's used.

Comment: What you'd rather expect instead of "двумя этажами выше"?

Comment: @shabunc We'd expect два этажа выше, like in English, because unlike you, we don't have a Russian mentality or language instinct, to say nothing of an instrumental case 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Russian instrumental is by far the most versatile case.

The classic work by Czech linguist Roman Mrazek, titled [*Синтаксис русского творительного*](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/handle/11222.digilib/103846) ("The syntax of Russian instrumental"), which contains almost 300 pages of dense text, begins with the following passage: *Предлагаемая книга имеет своим предметом синтаксис русского творительного падежа не во всём объёме, а лишь творительного беспредложного* ("The present book has as its subject the syntax of the Russian instrumental case not in its entirety, but only that of the prepositionless instrumental"). Ironically, this introductory sentence also makes use of one of the least common patterns of the instrumental.

The pattern you're talking about is in fact called almost the same as what you referred to it as: "the comparative instrumental of measure" (*компаративный творительный меры*) (*Mrazek 96*). It's used to form adverbial phrases that mark differences in measures: *это случилось годом раньше* "it had happened one year earlier", *магазин был двумя километрами ближе* "the store was two km closer", and, as in your example, *снайпер, двумя этажами выше* "(a) sniper, two floors (higher) up":

> - Несколькими метрами выше, у самой крыши, было большое гнездо злых ос. *[Клуб Почемучек // «Юный натуралист», 1975]*
> - — Ремонт часов, — читала Рита вывеску пятью шагами далее. *[Александр Вяльцев. Путешествия в одну сторону (1985-2000) // «Звезда», 2001]*
> - Но в своем творчестве он сумел подняться несколькими головами выше современного ему общества. *[Ю. Келдыш. М. И. Глинка // «Народное творчество», 1937]*

Similar, but not quite the same usages of the instrumental in Russian, are: marking factors in multiplication: *пя́тью пять — двадцать пять* (note the change in stress);  specifying generalized quantities: *я работал без отпуска годами* "I worked for years without a vacation"; and many others.

This construct has its origins in Proto-Indo-European and has parallels in other Indo-European languages: Latin *multo praestare* ("exceed by a lot", *многим превосходить*); Greek *πολλω μειζων* ("much greater", *многим более*), Baltic languages, Gothic and many others.

Comment: What an excellent answer to something that even after ten years of studying Russian, never occurred to me. And the fact that it dates back to PIE makes it even more fascinating.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148813/discussion-on-answer-by-quassnoi-is-the-instrumental-case-used-for-comparatives); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Even though there's already a good answer, I'd like to add that this use of instrumental case in Russian can be compared to the use of "by" in English.

> A mile closer > closer by a mile

> Beat him by two seconds

This "by" and the instrumental case in Russian are similar semantically, so it might be easier for you to reconcile them using this logic.

Comment: +1, never thought of it this way. It even works with "five by five" and "by the million" (_миллионами_). I wonder if it's related somehow or just a coincidence.

Comment: пятью (пять) -  в русском языке наречие, а не числительное. У наречий нет падежей.

Comment: Beat him by two seconds - опередил его на пару секунд/на две секунды. Или вы предлагаете переводить "опередил его парой секунд?" - это, полная чушь.

Comment: +1 And actually, *There's a sniper higher up by two floors* does kind of work as a possible translation of the Russian in the original question.

Answer (score -2):

"Снайпер. Двумя этажами выше, центральное окно." - неграмотная фраза, ошибка деления на предложения.

Двумя этажами выше, центральное окно. - нет ни сказуемого, ни подлежащего, таких предложений в русском языке не бывает, это два словосочетания без "хозяина" и без образа действия.

Снайпер, двумя этажами выше - центральное окно. - неполная фраза с пропущенным сказуемым. Хотя допустимо.

Снайпер, сидит двумя этажами выше - центральное окно. - полная фраза.

Сидит - как? - выше; сидит выше (чем?) - этажами.

Где сидит снайпер? - *Снайпер сидит этажами выше.* - возможно употребить без числительного.

То есть это обычное сочетание глагол + существительное-обстоятельство в [творительном падеже](https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/tvoritelnii-padeg), то есть с помощью чего реализовано действие: он доехал поездом/поездами, он бьет сильнее руками.

Если существительное стоит в косвенном падеже, а не в именительном, то [числительное будет зависеть от падежа существительного](https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/kolichestvennye-chislitelnye-sklonenie-kolichestvennyh-chislitelnyh#:%7E:text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%3A%C2%A0), а не наоборот:

*снайпер сидит выше двумя этажами* / или / *снайпер сидит двумя этажами выше* (в перестановке слов есть небольшой ньюанс в звучании, но это не так важно, если будет интересно, то напишу);

*он доехал пятью поездами*;

*он бьёт ногой и двумя руками*; - **нет компаратива**.

*он бьёт сильнее ногой и двумя руками*. - **тоже самое с компаративом**.

Также можно сравнить разницу в согласовании:

*сделал один взмах рукой* / *сделал одним взмахом руки* /

*убил двух слонов(два слона) одним взмахом руки* - he killed two elephants with one wave of his hand.

Компаратив имеет отношение к глаголу, так как в ряде случаев глагол не является полноценным и требует условия, но не он влияет на употребление или не употребление творительного падежа:

*Снайпер сидит выше двух других.*

Бывают идиоматические исключения: (посчитай) пя́тью пять = пять умножить на пять; дважды два и т.п. Однако [**пя́тью** и **дважды**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B&all=x#:%7E:text=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%2C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87.(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)) *это не числительные, а наречия* (сравнить с **пятью́ - числительное** в творительном падеже, с ударением на последнем слоге) Идиоматические - потому что такой счет существует только до двадцати... И умножения "одного" в такой форме нет.. а не, есть - оди́ножды один.

...................

Но, на самом деле, даже такое сочетание как "двумя ... выше" практически не употребляется!

И если рассуждать далее, то "тремя этажами выше" - это кривая фраза режущая слух. Так практически не говорят. Если нужно указать место или расположение в данный момент времени - измерить, ставят предлог "**на** или **в**":

**Снайпер сидит выше на два этажа.** / А не - *снайпер сидит двумя этажами выше.*

**Снайпер тяжелее кота в три раза.** / А не - *снайпер тяжелее кота тремя разами.*

Последнее намного более показательно относительно кривизны слога. Почему так не говорят? Потому что это согласование такого рода превращает числительное в наречие или местоимение. Для согласование измерений в предложение оставляют максимально четкое и полное употребление всех предлогов, потому что предлог - это указание на оператор объекта, а не вещи:

> *Ее прочность примерно в 10 раз выше, чем у стали.*

То есть, казалось бы, можно сказать: её прочность примерно в 10 раз выше стали, - но это уже нарушение научного стиля и переход к разговорному или литературному. Сказать же: "её прочность примерно *десятью разами* выше, чем у стали," - можно, это будет в целом понятно, но исключительно криво.

> *недавно зтот дворник за двумя метрами ситцу дрался два дня в очереди!*

Когда возможно-таки согласование через творительный падеж? Когда речь идет об образе действия, а не о конкретной мере:

> здешнее место южнее северной нашей столицы десятью градусами. Бесстужев.

> он удалится с оставшимися кровными десятью тысчонками в какое-нибудь мирное захолустье уездного городишка... Гоголь

То есть *десятью* тут не =10, а *примерно около десяти*, то есть это не числительное, а слово близкое к наречию и идиоматической фигуре речи.

В случае со снайпером, когда указано конкретное место положение - *на два этажа выше*, употребление идиоматического *двумя этажами* не обосновано.

То есть итог:

Употреблять измерение чего-то без предлога можно, ставя то, чем измеряют(метры, этажи, попугаи), в форму творительного падежа, но очень неверно, хотя с точки зрения западной грамматики должно быть верно. Поэтому такого понятия как "компаратив творительный меры" в русской грамматике нет.

Употребление творительного падежа при измерении будет давать скорее просторечное или идиоматическое звучание фразе.

Употребление творительного падежа числительного не связано с компаративом, и будет заменять часть речи числительного на местоимение.

> *песня спускается **тоном-двумя ниже**, смех умолкает*... Салтыков-Щедрин.

То есть допустимо было бы: *снайпер, **этажом-двумя** выше*, - где "двумя" это местоимение заменяющее слово этаж!

Употребление творительного падежа придает звучание примерно, около того, а не конкретное число меры.

Числительное по форме(два-дважды), не обязательно числительное, а это может быть также наречие и местоимение, с компаративом допустимо наречие или местоимение, употребление числительного выглядит очень сомнительно! Это как one, double or twin в английском могут заменять понятие, не являясь только числительными.

Ответ на вопрос: **нет, не используется, фраза абсолютно неграмотна написана и составлена.**

**(компаративный творительный меры)** - 0 упоминаний Яше дает, кроме данного поста, может это какой-то другой язык?

[image]